# How to import custom image dataset for Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a custom dataset that looks like this:

```
├── data
│   └── train
│       ├── 1
│       │   ├── x.jpg
│       │   ├── ...
│       ├── 2
│       │   ├── 1.jpg
│       │   ├── 2.jpg
│       │   ├── 3.jpg
│       │   ├── ...
│       ├── 3
│       │   ├── ...
...     ...     ...
```

and i was wondering how i may import this as a tf.data.dataset of the correct format such that I am able to pass this code

```
for image_batch, label_batch in train_batches.take(1):
   pass

image_batch.shape
```

for use to input into the pretrained MobileNet model. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do the it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

# Here, I am assuming that the directories in /data/train are the class labels
train_dir = '/data/train/'

# Find the labels
labels = os.listdir(train_dir)

# Pair up the image path and its corresponding label
label_pairs = [(os.path.join(train_dir, label, path), int(label)) for label in labels for path in os.listdir(f'{train_dir}{label}')]

# Now, separate the paths and labels.
#The step before was to make sure that the paths and labels were ordered.
train_img_paths = [pair[0] for pair in label_pairs]
train_img_labels = [pair[1] for pair in label_pairs]

# Convert the paths and labels to a tf.data.Dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_img_paths, train_img_labels))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your code, however, I am getting a IndexError: list index out of range in line 12 :   train_img_labels = [pair[1] for pair in label_pairs]
Also, I will just use the dataset as the raw_train, raw_validation and raw_test datasets in the tutorial right?

Comment: tunrs out the line had a slight syntax issue : the correct one seems to be label_pairs = [(os.path.join(train_dir, label, path), int(label)) for label in labels for path in os.listdir(f'{train_dir}{label}')]

Comment: Thank you, sorry for asking to be spoonfed but could you point me as to how I may use this dataset in the transfer learning tutorial [here?](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)

Comment: If you need to separate your data into training, validation, and test sets, you might be better off splitting your directories as such and repeating what I have above. Otherwise, to use the data set, you can do `dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)`. Then you can call `.fit()` on your model and specify `x=dataset`. For an infinitely repeating data set (this happens when you call `repeat()` without an integer specifying how many epochs to repeat for), you need to specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument. This can be calculated as `len(train_img_paths)//BATCH_SIZE`.